# How to submit MapReduce job from DataNode to JobTracker?

Tags: hadoop

I have this doubt where I am running a 12 node cluster with separate NameNode and JobTracker. I can execute MapReduce job from JobTracker but I want to submit the jobs to JobTracker from any of my 10 DataNodes. Is it possible and If yes how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as hadoop is on the path (on each node), and the configuration for the cluster has been properly distributed to each data node.

In fact you don't necessarily need the configuration to be properly distributed, you'll just need to configure the jobtracker and hdfs urls accordingly (look at the GenericOptionsParser options for `-jt` and `-fs` options).

See this page for more information on generic options: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options